# Data is not saved if use custom property editor in Umbraco

Tags: c#, angular, umbraco

I create custom property editor which takes all available languages in Umbraco like:

```
angular.module("umbraco").controller("MyLanguageController", function ($scope, myLanguageService) {
   $scope.items = [];

   myLanguageService.getAll().then( function( result ) {
      if( result && result.data && result.data.length ) {
         $scope.items = result.data;
      }
   } );
});
```

and

```
angular.module("umbraco.resources")
   .factory("myLanguageService", function ($http) {

      return {
         getAll: function () {
            return $http.get("/umbraco/backoffice/MyControllerSide/GetAll", { "dataType": "json" });
         }
      };
});
```

The view:

```
<div ng-controller="MyLanguageController" id="language">
   <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in items" class="checkbox">
         <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="{{item.IsoCode}}"> {{item.CultureName}}
         </label>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

The package manifest contains:

```
{
    propertyEditors: [
        {
            alias: "MyLanguageAlias",
            name: "Language Selector",
            icon: "icon-umb-translation",
            hideLabel: true,
            valueType: "JSON",
            editor: {
                view: "~/App_Plugins/MyLanguageSelector/backoffice/view.html"
            }
        }
    ],
  ...
```

and C# code:

```
  [HttpGet]
  public JsonResult GetAll()
  {
     IEnumerable<ILanguage> languages = ApplicationContext.Services.LocalizationService.GetAllLanguages() ?? new List<ILanguage>(0);
     IEnumerable<TranslationLanguageModel> model =
        languages.Select(s => new MyLanguageModel { CultureName = s.CultureInfo.DisplayName, IsoCode = s.IsoCode });

     return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
```

I created new data type in Umbraco/Developer section, and I add it in document type:

[image]

When I save document, the value for that property is null. I don't understand why.

And when come back to content, then nothing is checked.

What should I do ?

---

**Update 1**

If I put:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="{{item.IsoCode}}"  ng-model="models[item.IsoCode]"/> {{item.CultureName}}
```

then I receive always `True` instead of object/json.

---

**Update 2**

I succeeded to do by adding `ng-change` for checkbox and modify `$scope.model.value` value

`<input type="checkbox" value="item.IsoCode" ng-change="change()" ng-model="models[item.IsoCode]"/> {{item.CultureName}}`

and

```
$scope.models = {};

$scope.change = function () {
  $scope.model.value = $scope.models;
}
```

then it works !

Answer (score 1):

Your checkboxes have no model to save their state to, so Umbraco has nothing to save. Try adding ng-model="model.value" (or something thereabout) to your checkbox and see if that does something more :-)

Comment: I put like `<input type="checkbox" value="{{item.IsoCode}}" ng-model="checkbx" /> {{item.CultureName}}` but same thing

Comment: Yeah, but I think Umbraco needs it to be model.value. You should be able to google an example of this? :-/

Comment: Ok, if I put `ng-model='model.value'` then when I check one checkbox -> will check all others checkbox

Comment: Ok, maybe model.value[$index] then?

Comment: I got `TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '0' of string 'True'`

Comment: I managed to do like: `ng-model='models[item.IsoCode]'` but the value comes like: `True` ... instead of object/json